# user role, showing screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show a popup readonly screen only to users who are not logged in as "Admin". So all the other users can see only  the Popup readonly screen.

I try it like this:

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{


<div id="eventContent" title="Event Details" style="display:none">


    Date: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
    Start event: <span id="eventTime"></span><br>
    Duration: <span id="eventDuration"></span><br><br>

</div>
}
```

Thank you

I will make it more cleared

I have two screens:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{


<div id="eventContent" title="Event Details" style="display:none">


    Date: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
    Start event: <span id="eventTime"></span><br>
    Duration: <span id="eventDuration"></span><br><br>

</div>
}

<div class="container">



    <div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div>

</div>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <div id="popupEventForm" class="modal hide" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header"> <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp;Appointment</h3></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="EventForm" class="well">
                <input type="hidden" id="eventID">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Event title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventTitle"><br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Scheduled date</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventDate" readonly><br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Scheduled time</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventTime"><br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Appointment length (minutes)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventDuration"><br />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnPopupCancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-mini">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnPopupSave" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success ">Save event</button>
            @*<button type="button" id="btnPopupUpdate" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Update event</button>*@
            <button type="button" id="btnPopupDelete" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger right ">Delete event</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

eventContent - is for users who are not admin(it is readonly) and the other screen is for admin, where the admin can add a agenda item. But if I click now on a agenda item(not logged in as admin) I see both screens

Oke, I found it:

```
@if ( !Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

<div id="eventContent" title="Event Details" style="display:none">


    Date: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
    Start event: <span id="eventTime"></span><br>
    Duration: <span id="eventDuration"></span><br><br>

</div>
}

else



{
    <div id="popupEventForm" class="modal hide" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header"> <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp;Appointment</h3></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="EventForm" class="well">
                <input type="hidden" id="eventID">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Event title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventTitle"><br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Scheduled date</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventDate" readonly><br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Scheduled time</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventTime"><br />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Appointment length (minutes)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="eventDuration"><br />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnPopupCancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-mini">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="btnPopupSave" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success ">Save event</button>
            @*<button type="button" id="btnPopupUpdate" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Update event</button>*@
            <button type="button" id="btnPopupDelete" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger right ">Delete event</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting any Authenticated User in your If condition.  Try changing it to:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
```

to get only authenticated users that are not admin.

If you mean anybody (authenticated or otherwise) that is not admin:

```
@if (!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
```

Comment: Jle, thank you for your answare. but I can still see the other screen, where only admin can edit or save the agenda item. I updated my post

Comment: Oke, I found the solution